# Dart fails to infer type of sub class

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, riverpod

I have this code that I've reduced to the file below.

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

// this class disctates what other classes do
abstract class BaseUtils<T> {
  T fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}

// Model to be used
class SampleModel extends BaseUtils {
  late int? id;

  SampleModel({
    this.id,
  });

  @override
  SampleModel fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SampleModel(
      id: json['id'],
    );
  }
}

// First service
class ServiceA<T extends BaseUtils> {}

final serviceAProvider = Provider<ServiceA>((ref) {
  return ServiceA();
});

class ServiceB {
  final ServiceA<SampleModel> _service;
  ServiceB(this._service);

  void func() {
    print(_service);
  }
}

final serviceBProvider = Provider<ServiceB>((ref) {
  final _a = ref.read(serviceAProvider);
  //// Error here
  return ServiceB(_a);
});
```

`ServiceB`depends on `ServiceA` to get data in form of `SampleModel`.
However I get an IDE error `The argument type 'ServiceA<BaseUtils<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ServiceA<SampleModel>'` which shouldn't happen

What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ServiceA` is a generic class, when you write `Provider<ServiceA>` without specifying a type parameter for `ServiceA`, Dart implicitly uses the broadest type possible that satisfies its type constraints.  For `ServiceA<T>`, since `T` must extend `BaseUtils`, `ServiceA` with no explicit type parameter is equivalent to `ServiceA<BaseUtils>`, which in turn is equivalent to `ServiceA<BaseUtils<dynamic>>` due to `BaseUtils` being a generic class with no constraint on its type parameter.

The error message is correct: you cannot safely assign a `ServiceA<BaseUtils<dynamic>>` to a `ServiceA<SampleModel>`.  You have a supertype (`ServiceA<BaseUtils<dynamic>>`) and a subtype (`ServiceA<SampleModel>`).  Although the subtype is a supertype, not every supertype is a subtype!

Enabling the [`strict-raw-types` option](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) in your `analysis_options.yaml` should help catch similar mistakes in the future.

I'm not experienced with `package:provider`, but I expect that the fix would be to provide explicit types for your generic classes.  For example:

> ```dart
> final serviceAProvider = Provider<ServiceA>((ref) {
>   return ServiceA();
> })
> ```

maybe should be:

```dart
final serviceAProvider = Provider<ServiceA<SampleModel>>((ref) {
  return ServiceA<SampleModel>();
})
```

Since this would require a separate `serviceAProvider` variable for each type, it'd probably be cleaner to make a generic function so that callers can specify a type parameter:

```dart
final _serviceAMap = <Type, Provider<ServiceA>>{};

Provider<ServiceA<T>> getServiceAProvider<T extends BaseUtils>() {
  var provider = _serviceAMap[T];
  if (provider != null) {
    return provider as Provider<ServiceA<T>>;
  }
  
  return _serviceAMap[T] = Provider<ServiceA<T>>((ref) => ServiceA<T>());
}

final serviceBProvider = Provider<ServiceB>((ref) {
  final _a = ref.read(getServiceAProvider<SampleModel>());
  return ServiceB(_a);
});
```

Comment: Thank you... Can you copy the code above onto an IDE... Coz I'm getting `The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'T'.` and `'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound 'BaseUtils<dynamic>' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'BaseUtils<dynamic>'` upon  using your solution

Comment: @john Sorry, I misread your code and mistakenly thought that `serviceAProvider`  was part of the `ServiceA` class.  In that case, you will need a separate `serviceAProvider` variable for each type of `ServiceA` that you care about.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I want `ServiceA` to be used by multiple services like `ServiceB`.  It needs to be dynamic

Comment: @john You could try performing an explicit `as` cast to appease static type-checking, but if `serviceAProvider` ever returns something that isn't actually a `ServiceA<SampleModel>` as required by `serviceBProvider`, you will end up with runtime errors.

Comment: @john Also, what I said before wouldn't prevent `ServiceA` (the generic class) from being used by multiple services such as `ServiceB`.  What you wouldn't be able to do is have multiple `serviceXProvider`s depend on a single `serviceAProvider` variable.

Comment: I tried casting but experienced some runtime errors. How would I structure the code to accommodate all services. With each service returning a different model ?

Comment: Still getting `Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
Try removing the reference to the type parameter, or making the member an instance member`.. Can you try the code on an IDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242904/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-john).